# Applying XGBoost on a Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: regression, xgboost, montecarlo

I am currently looking into a special kind of regression analysis. Instead of a "natural phenomenon" I observe the outcome of a Monte Carlo simulation.

Does anyone have some experience with this kind of problem? I was wondering what it means for the training of an XGBoost model.

To give some further details: My training set consists of approx. 100'000 observations and the number of predictors is around 100. Setting up the entire MC simulation is quite time consuming. Hence, I wanted to train an XGBoost that can quickly predict the outcome of the MC simulation given there are new input data (in particular: observed financial market data).

I achieve quite a good (out of sample) fit when the training is based on

> 3000 rounds (trees)
> max_depth = 3
> eta = 0.18

While the in-sample fit has generally a very high R^2, the out of sample fit is sometimes a bit volatile. However, I am pretty sure the high R^2 is not an overfit but just resulting from the fact that there is a very clear relationship (set of formulas) between the predictors (observed input data x scenarios) and the response (outcome of the MC simulation).

Any ideas how to improve the stability of the out of sample predictions?

I did already an exhaustive grid search on the hyperparameters. While the in-scope fit is usually very high, the out of sample predictions are a bit volatile. If anyone has experience with regressions on MC simulation, I am happy to get some inputs.